# Does pulling a public image from Docker Hub require authentication?

Tags: maven, docker, spotify-docker-client

I have a CI/CD pipeline running.  During the run, I'm using the [Spotify docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) to do the Docker build.

Recently my builds have begun failing when it tries to pull Payara Micro version 172 as the first line in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM payara/micro:172
```

I see this in my logs:

```
74297 [INFO] 53853 [INFO] Building image my.private.repo.io/arglebargle/foobar:38a635da5622d90dc09d71757c734fe52539bac3
75522 [INFO] Step 1 : FROM payara/micro:172
76539 [INFO] 56095 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
76540 [INFO] 56095 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
76540 [INFO] 56095 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
76540 [INFO] 56096 [INFO] Total time: 55.094 s
76540 [INFO] 56096 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-27T19:39:26Z
76783 [INFO] 56336 [INFO] Final Memory: 52M/495M
76783 [INFO] 56339 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
76785 [INFO] 56339 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.14:build (Build Docker image) on project foobar: Exception caught: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/payara/micro/manifests/172: unauthorized: incorrect username or password -> [Help 1]
```

I don't currently have anything in my Maven setup that says anything about logging in to Docker Hub, and again, this is a public image—so I would have expected it to just work (as it has been working in the past).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check for a network proxy.

Comment: "Unauthorized" means "proxy couldn't connect"?  I am indeed behind a proxy.

Comment: Unauthorized is an error from your proxy, not from docker. Your request never made it past your proxy.

Comment: OK, thank you; I'll investigate, but that seems odd since my proxy requires neither a username nor a password.  There's also this: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/246

Comment: From the same machine, can you do a docker pull of the image? That will tell you if it's a proxy problem or a Spotify problem. I don't know anything about the latter.